# Google Developer Console Github push to deploy private repository

Tags: google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-console

I am trying to connect a private GitHub repository to a Google App Engine app via the Google Developer Console. I am entering the url to my repo, consenting, and then hitting connect. The page will redirect to

https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?...

then back to the dev console with the error:

"GitHub repository to enable push-to-deploy"

Note that my repo is private, but I would imagine this feature is supposed to work for private repos anyway. The very first time I tried, I accepted the permissions through GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have access to the repo. I am not the original owner. The original owner was able to add the repo with no problems.

Comment: I am also having this problem, but I am the original owner, so I don't know what else to do :-/  Guess I will just use google's repo and only push when I want to build.